# error in getting proper address pointed by marker

Tags: javascript, cordova, google-maps, phonegap-plugins

I am developing android app using phonegap where i am pointing marker on google map to specified latitude and longitude ,on click og marker i am trying to display infowindow which displays its address using response.originaddress[0].But in my below code its showing wrong address what should i change in my below code.

```
   var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
   var parms = query.split('&');
   var pos = parms[0].indexOf('=');
        if (pos > 0) {
            currentlat = parms[0].substring(pos + 1);               
                pos = parms[1].indexOf('=');
                currentlong = parms[1].substring(pos + 1);
        var orgplace = new google.maps.LatLng(currentlat, currentlong);

  service.getDistanceMatrix(
     {
         origins: [orgplace],
         destinations: datatblAcc,
         travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
         unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
         avoidHighways: false,
         avoidTolls: false
     }, callback);

 function callback(response, status) {

        var tblhtml = document.getElementById('listaddress');
        if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
        document.getElementById('view-loadingpoi').style.display = "none";

        } else {
        setTimeout(function(){
          var origins = response.originAddresses;
            var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
            var outputDiv = document.getElementById('outputDiv');
            outputDiv.innerHTML = '';
            deleteOverlays();

            var data = '';
            var localplace = new google.maps.LatLng(currentlat, currentlong);
            if ((currentlat == 0))
            {
                localplace = new google.maps.LatLng(-65.994173, 78.127421);

                    currentlat = "-65.994173";
                    currentlong = "78.127421";
            }

            maploc = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapdisp"), {
                center: localplace,
                zoom: 14,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                disableDefaultUI: true
            });               

            var image = 'images/greenpointer.png';
            var pointcur = new google.maps.LatLng(currentlat, currentlong);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: pointcur,
                icon: image,
                map: maploc
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (event) {
                if (infowindow) infowindow.close();

                var evelatitu = currentlong.split('.')[1];

                if (((currentlat.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '').indexOf(event.latLng.lat())) !== -1) && ((currentlong.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '').indexOf(event.latLng.lng().toFixed(evelatitu.length))) !== -1)) {
                    var txthtml = "<div class='mappopuploc'>My Location<br/>" + response.originAddresses[0] + "</div>";
                    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({

                        content: txthtml
                    });


                    infowindow.open(maploc, marker);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use marker title in marker click event listener in order to get accurate address

function callback(response, status) {

```
    var tblhtml = document.getElementById('listaddress');
    if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
    document.getElementById('view-loadingpoi').style.display = "none";

    } else {
    setTimeout(function(){
      var origins = response.originAddresses;
        var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
        var outputDiv = document.getElementById('outputDiv');
        outputDiv.innerHTML = '';
        deleteOverlays();

        var data = '';
        var localplace = new google.maps.LatLng(currentlat, currentlong);
        if ((currentlat == 0))
        {
            localplace = new google.maps.LatLng(-65.994173, 78.127421);

                currentlat = "-65.994173";
                currentlong = "78.127421";
        }

        maploc = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapdisp"), {
            center: localplace,
            zoom: 14,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            disableDefaultUI: true
        });               

        var image = 'images/greenpointer.png';
        var pointcur = new google.maps.LatLng(currentlat, currentlong);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: pointcur,
            icon: image,
            map: maploc,
            title: response.originAddresses[0]
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (event) {
            if (infowindow) infowindow.close();

            var evelatitu = currentlong.split('.')[1];

            if (((currentlat.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '').indexOf(event.latLng.lat())) !== -1) && ((currentlong.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '').indexOf(event.latLng.lng().toFixed(evelatitu.length))) !== -1)) {
                var txthtml = "<div class='mappopuploc'>My Location<br/>" +  this.title+ "</div>";
                infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({

                    content: txthtml
                });


                infowindow.open(maploc, marker);
            }
        });
```

}